# D3.js Draw vertical line after every 2 bar and draw x-axis label on the top of bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wanted to create a vertical line after every 2 bars and also the labels on the top of the bar chart.
[image: I have tried to create the following bar chart]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var dataArray = [
      {
       "xData" : 2016,
       "yData" : 38
      },
      {
       "xData" : 2017,
       "yData" : 27
      },
      {
       "xData" : 2016,
       "yData" : 50
      },
      {
       "xData" : 2017,
       "yData" : 27
      }  ];
drawBarchart("graph",dataArray,"count",700,400);
}
);


function drawBarchart(containerId, dataArray, yAxisText, chartAreaWidth,
  chartAreaHeight) {

 
 var margin = {
  top : 20,
  right : 20,
  bottom : 30,
  left : 40
 }, width = chartAreaWidth - margin.left - margin.right, height = chartAreaHeight
   - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

 var y = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ]);

 //var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").tickFormat(formatPercent);
 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");
 
 var svg = d3.select("#" + containerId).append("svg").attr("width",
   width + margin.left + margin.right).attr("height",
   height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g").attr("transform",
   "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 /* d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) { */
 y.domain([ 0, d3.max(dataArray, function(d) {
  return d.yData;
 }) ]);

 svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis).append("text").attr(
   "transform", "rotate(-90)").attr("y", 6).attr("dy", ".71em").style(
   "text-anchor", "end").text(yAxisText);

 svg.selectAll(".bar").data(dataArray).enter().append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar").attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * width/dataArray.length;
   }).attr("width", (width/dataArray.length)-20).attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.yData);
   }).attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.yData);
   });
    
    svg.selectAll("text.x").data(dataArray).enter()
        .append("text").attr("class", "x")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
   return (i * width/dataArray.length) + ((width/dataArray.length)-20)/2;
     })
        .attr("y", height + 20)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.xData; });

 /* }); */

 function type(d) {
  d.yData = +d.yData;
  return d;
 }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph">
    
</div>
```

[Code also available in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orduxwfL/).

Comment: Please include your code into the question. You can do so with a Stack Snippet (use the `{}` icon on the [edit] page to insert the code), which is interactive like a JSFiddle is but has the benefit that other users can easily modify it to answer your question.

Comment: I've copied the jsfiddle into a stack snippet for you, this time. For future reference, if you should be using the <> icon to enter a snippet, not the {} icon which is for inserting code. ANy time you'd use a jsfiddle, a snippet will probably do the job just as well and be more convenient for SO users.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this javascript code instead of your javascript code.

```
  //Width and height
  var w = 500;
  var h = 100;
  var barPadding = 1;

  var dataset = [5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25];
  i=0;
 //Create SVG element
  var svg = d3.select("#graph")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

  //Add bars to the generated svg element
  svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
   return i * (w / dataset.length);
  })
 .attr("y", function(d) {
   return h - (d * 4);
  })

  //setting dynamic width for each bar with bar padding acting as the space between bars
 .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)

 //multiplying data value with 4 to increase the height of the bars 
 .attr("height", function(d) {
  return d * 4;
 })

   //apply dynamic colors
   .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "rgb(5, 2, " + (d * 10) + ")";
   });

   //set the label
   svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .text(function(d) {
   return d;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
   return i * (w / dataset.length) + (w / dataset.length - barPadding) / 2;
  })
 .attr("y", function(d) {
  if((i%2)==0){
  i++;
  return h-(h-10);
 }else{
   i++;
  return '';
 }
 })
.attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
.attr("font-size", "11px")
.attr("fill", "black");
```

Comment: `h-(h-10)` == `10`. You can filter the selection so you don't have to add empty text elements, `i` can be passed to `y` callback like in `x` callback, no  need for ugly global `i`